# NSTableView: second Column appears when it shouldn't

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have an NSTableView with only one column. When I change the Windows size, the TableView sticks to the Windows borders, as it should:
[ScreenShot Small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfgD.png)

However, when I expand the windows frame to much (for example, when using full screen) suddenly a second column appears:
[ScreenShot FullScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV9UB.png)

I have no idea, why this is happening. I can't expand the first cell manually using this little resize indicator, it seems like the cell inside the tableview just wouldn't be able to grow more...

Here is a picture of the TableViews Attributes Inspector:
[ScreenShot AttributeInspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaPr9.png)

I didn't find any constraints or width settings that would explain this.

I would be really greatful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the column sizing of tableView to Uniform in attributes inspector.

Also in your size inspector, check and adjust maximum width  for the column depending on your window max allowable width.